# Update label inside UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have created this using UICollectionView When I click the `Add(+)` or `Remove(-)` button then I want to update the label. How can I achieve this?

[image]

**MainViewController.swift**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if(collectionView == ProductCollectionView){
        let Productcell = self.ProductCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:"ProductCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ProductCollectionViewCell

        Productcell.AddOrMinusLabel.text = "\(bestOfferProductCount[indexPath.row])"
        Productcell.ProdName.text = bestOfferProductName[indexPath.row]
        Productcell.ProdPrice.text = bestOfferProductPrice[indexPath.row]
        Productcell.ProdtOrgPrice.text = bestOfferProductOriginalPrice[indexPath.row]
        Productcell.ProdWeight.text = bestOfferProductWeight[indexPath.row]+" "+bestOfferProductUnit[indexPath.row]
        Productcell.ProductImage.setImageFromURl(stringImageUrl: bestOfferProductImage[indexPath.row])

        return Productcell
    }

}
```

**ProductCollectionViewCell.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ProductCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var ProdPrice: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var ProdtOrgPrice: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var ProductImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var ProdName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var ProdWeight: UILabel!

}
```

Comment: Using multiple arrays as data source is a horrible design. 1) Use a **class** as model 2) Pass the model item in `cellForRow` to the cell 3) In the cell implement the `IBAction`s,  make the changes and update the model simultaneously. And please conform to the naming convention that variable names start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: i have just implemented showing the data in collectionView. Than i don't have any idea to do. just searching for solutions. i don't get any solution related to this. I am beginner to ios development

Comment: @vadian Thanks. i get your point. but if i want to add or remove the product quantity and show to the label how to done that by clicking + or - Buttons

Comment: Please look at 3) in my previous comment. If you have a reference to the data model you can do everything in the cell assumed that you keep the model in sync.

Comment: Personally, I prefer not to have the cell update the model directly. Have the cell implement a delegation protocol so that it can notify the view controller about the +/- taps and then the view controller can update the model and refresh the item.

Comment: @vadian i am asking for how to perform an Clicking Action By pressing the (+) or (-). if i click the + button it will update the model and data updated in UI. But my question is where to perform an Button Click Action and Updating the Model and how to know which items Button is clicked

Comment: • Add two `UIButton`s. • Implement two `IBAction`s. • Connect the buttons to the actions. • Add the logic to increment and decrement the related value in the model. • Update the label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this using protocols,
Add this to your cell's class and add the IBAction's to UIButton.

```
class ProductCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

  @IBOutlet weak var ProdPrice: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var ProdtOrgPrice: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var ProductImage: UIImageView!
  @IBOutlet weak var ProdName: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var ProdWeight: UILabel!

  weak open var delegate: ProductCollectionViewCellDelegate?

  @IBAction func btnIncrement(_ sender: UIButton)
  {
    if let d = self.delegate {
      d.didTapOnIncrement(cell: self)
    }
  }

  @IBAction func btnDecrement(_ sender: UIButton)
  {
    if let d = self.delegate {
      d.didTapOnDecrement(cell: self)
    }
  }
}

protocol ProductCollectionViewCellDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {
    func didTapOnIncrement(cell: ProductCollectionViewCell)
    func didTapOnDecrement(cell: ProductCollectionViewCell)
}
```

Now in you cellForItemAt method, add this line -\

```
cell.delegate = self
```

Now confirm that delegate confirms the protocols. In this example, I suppose it is your viewController.

```
extension ViewController: ProductCollectionViewCellDelegate {

  func didTapOnIncrement(cell: ProductCollectionViewCell) {
    //let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPath(for: cell)
    //You have the cell's instance here. You can also get the indexPath by delegate method.
    //You can add the increment-decrement logic here.
  }

  func didTapOnDecrement(cell: ProductCollectionViewCell) {
    //let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPath(for: cell)
    //You have the cell's instance here. You can also get the indexPath by delegate method.
    //You can add the increment-decrement logic here.
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

i say, always configure your cell data inside the cell class

```
import UIKit

class ProductCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var addOrMinusLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var ProdPrice: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var ProdtOrgPrice: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var ProductImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var ProdName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var ProdWeight: UILabel!

var count = 1 {
    didSet{
        self.addOrMinusLabel.text = "\(count)"
    }
}


 func configureData(count: Int) {
    self.count = count
}

@IBAction func subtract(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.count -= 1

}
@IBAction func add(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.count += 1
}

}
```

and in your view controller

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

if(collectionView == ProductCollectionView){
    let Productcell = self.ProductCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:"ProductCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ProductCollectionViewCell
    Productcell.configureData(count: (bestOfferProductCount[indexPath.row]))

   // do try to configure these below labels also within cell class 
    Productcell.ProdName.text = bestOfferProductName[indexPath.row]
    Productcell.ProdPrice.text = bestOfferProductPrice[indexPath.row]
    Productcell.ProdtOrgPrice.text = bestOfferProductOriginalPrice[indexPath.row]
    Productcell.ProdWeight.text = bestOfferProductWeight[indexPath.row]+" "+bestOfferProductUnit[indexPath.row]
    Productcell.ProductImage.setImageFromURl(stringImageUrl: bestOfferProductImage[indexPath.row])

    return Productcell
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to approach this.

### 1.  Old Delegate mechanism

When you're dequeuing a Cell, you have to removeAllObservers, then AddTarget from cell to your ViewController for tapEvents of Plus and Minus sign with sender. In your callee method, you have to fetch it's superView (until you reach the collectionViewCell view) and then ask from UICollectoinView for itemIndex for that cell, and update your view and cell and model accordingly.

### 2. Using Closures

You can define two closures one for plus and one for minus in your Cell and instead of adding Target to your viewController, add targets to your cell and call corresponding closures and each time you're trying to return a Cell, set those closures and act on them accordingly.

```
class CustomCell: UICollectionCell {
    var plusAction: (() -> Void)?
    var minusAction: (() -> Void)?
    @IBOutlet var counterLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction plusTapped() {
        plusAction?()
    }

    @IBAction minusTapped() {
        minusAction?()
    }
}
```

and in your cellDequeue method:

```
cellForItemAtIndexPath(/*...other parameters...*/) -> UICollectionCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueCell(/*...other parameters...*/) as! CustomCell
    // other customizations
    // weak allocation in closure might not be needed here since closure reference is nullable on the other end, but i wrote it just in-case.
    cell.plusAction = { [weak weakCell = cell] in
        let counter = 0 // i said 0 for ex, You actually have to have them stored somewhere (even initial zeros) and fetch the actual value for this indexPath
        let newCounter = counter + 1
        // update your Model with newCounter
        weakCell?.counterLabel.text = "\(newCounter)"
    }

    cell.minusAction = { [weak weakCell = cell] in
        let counter = 0 // i said 0 for ex, You actually have to have them stored somewhere (even initial zeros) and fetch the actual value for this indexPath
        let newCounter = counter - 1
        // update your Model with newCounter
        weakCell?.counterLabel.text = "\(newCounter)"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple n sober

add this code in your `viewcontroller`

```
@IBAction func onBtnPlusClick(_ sender : UIButton) {
    if let cell = sender.superview?.superview as? ProductCollectionViewCell {
        let indexPath = yourCollectionViewOutlet.indexPath(for: cell)
    //Do whatever you want or update your data model values
         yourCollectionViewOutlet.reloadData()
    }
}

@IBAction func onBtnMinusClick(_ sender : UIButton) {
        if let cell = sender.superview?.superview as? ProductCollectionViewCell {
            let indexPath = yourCollectionViewOutlet.indexPath(for: cell)
        //Do whatever you want or update your data model values
         yourCollectionViewOutlet.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

In your `cellForItemAt` add target to button

```
btnPlus.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self. onBtnPlusClick(_:)), for: .touchUpInside) 
btnMinus.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self. onBtnPlusClick(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Add two button outlets in `ProductCollectionViewCell` class

```
@IBOutlet var btnPlus : UIButton!
@IBOutlet var btnMinus : UIButton!
```

That's it, hope this help